# Windows Server 2003 R2 Assigned Letter C to System Reserved Partition

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 2003 R2 server that installed a System Reserved Partition of 100MB and the Boot Partition on Disk 0. For some unknown reason, the System Reserved partition is assigned drive letter C.  The Boot Partition is assigned Drive D.  Everything works fine under this configuration.  The OS runs from Drive D.

My problem is that I am attempting to install some software that requires use of drive C for the installation process and the 70MB available on C is insufficient. Since the Boot drive was assigned D, I'm sure I can't just wiggle the drive letters around since any registry entries that refer to drive D would point to the wrong place.

It looks like the disk manager will let me remove the drive letter from the System Reserved partition. If I remove the drive letter and add another drive and call it C will that work? Other systems I have do not have a drive letter for the System Reserved partition (but they do have the boot partition as drive C). Any thoughts would be appreciated.